# connect to SauceLabs open chrome dev tool get exception:org.openqa.selenium.devtools.devtoolsexception: unable to create devtools connection

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, devtools, saucelabs

How to open chrome dev tool on remote driver, in my test I was connecting to SauceLabs however when I try to obtain chrome dev tools instance, immediately got this exception:

> org.openqa.selenium.devtools.devtoolsexception: unable to create devtools connection

```
Selenium version 4.8
Chrome ver 108,109
```

In a nut shell we need monitoring some HTTP request/response as part of function testing. My local works fine.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.